# RDD CountApproximate taking far longer than requested timeout

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In an attempt to reduce the time spent on gathering `count`s of `DataFrame` rows the `RDD.countApproximate()` is being invoked. It has the following signature:

```
def countApprox(
    timeout: Long,
    confidence: Double = 0.95): PartialResult[BoundedDouble] = withScope {
```

I have attempted to limit the output calculation to sixty seconds. Notice also the *very* low accuracy requirement of `0.10`:

```
val waitSecs = 60
val cnt = inputDf.rdd.countApprox(waitSecs * 1000, 0.10).getFinalValue.mean
```

However the actual time is .. ***17 minutes*** ??

[image]

That time is almost the same as what was required to generate the data in the first place (*19* minutes) !

So then - what is the **use** of this api: is there any way to get it to actually save some meaningful fraction of the *exact* time calculation?

**TL;DR** (See accepted answer): use `initialValue` instead of `getFinalValue`

Comment: Are you sure you are not generating the dataframe again (i.e. did you cache the dataframe)?

Comment: This is the *first* time the dataframe is being generated: i.e. it is the first *action* on the dataframe. It is too large for caching to be a preferred option.

Comment: Since it's the first action, then the problem should lie elsewhere.

Comment: Do you have any evidence otherwise? i.e. have you run this method on a dataset that takes say 30 minutes to do a full `count` - and then seen that `countApproximate` takes a fraction of that time?  If so then please post an example.

Comment: I was probably a bit unclear, I just meant that the problem should not be with the cache/multiple actions as I thought it could be. I agree that the approximate count should save a lot of time, otherwise it is basically a useless function. I will try look into it some more when I have time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please note the return type in the `approxCount` definition. It's a partial result.

```
def countApprox(
    timeout: Long,
    confidence: Double = 0.95): PartialResult[BoundedDouble] = withScope {
```

Now, please pay attention on how it is being used:

```
val waitSecs = 60
val cnt = inputDf.rdd.countApprox(waitSecs * 1000, 0.10).**getFinalValue**.mean
```

According to spark scala doc, [`getFinalValue`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.partial.PartialResult@getFinalValue():R) is blocking method which means it will wait for complete operation to finish.

**Whereas [`initialValue`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.partial.PartialResult@initialValue:R) can be fetched within specified timeout. So the following snippet will not block further operations after timeout,**

```
val waitSecs = 60
val cnt = inputDf.rdd.countApprox(waitSecs * 1000, 0.10).initialValue.mean
```

Please note the downside of using `countApprox(timeout, confidence).initialValue` is that even after getting the value, it will continue counting till it get final count that you would have obtained using `getFinalValue` and still will hold the resources till operation is complete.

Now the use of this api is not to get blocked at count operation.

Reference: https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201505.mbox/%3C747872034.1520543.1431544429083.JavaMail.yahoo@mail.yahoo.com%3E

Now lets validate our assumption of non blocking operation on spark2-shell. Lets create random dataframe and perform `count`, `approxCount` with `getFinalValue` and `approxCount` with `initialValue`:

```
scala> val schema = StructType((0 to 10).map(n => StructField(s"column_$n", StringType)))
schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(column_0,StringType,true), StructField(column_1,StringType,true), StructField(column_2,StringType,true), StructField(column_3,StringType,true), StructField(column_4,StringType,true), StructField(column_5,StringType,true), StructField(column_6,StringType,true), StructField(column_7,StringType,true), StructField(column_8,StringType,true), StructField(column_9,StringType,true), StructField(column_10,StringType,true))

scala> val rows = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq[Row](), 100).mapPartitions { _ => { Range(0, 100000).map(m => Row(schema.map(_ => Random.alphanumeric.filter(_.isLower).head.toString).toList: _*)).iterator } }
rows: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = MapPartitionsRDD[1] at mapPartitions at <console>:32

scala> val inputDf = spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame(rows, schema)
inputDf: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [column_0: string, column_1: string ... 9 more fields]

//Please note that cnt will be displayed only when all tasks are completed
scala> val cnt = inputDf.rdd.count
cnt: Long = 10000000

scala> val waitSecs = 60
waitSecs: Int = 60

//cntApproxFinal will be displayed only when all tasks are completed.
scala> val cntApprxFinal = inputDf.rdd.countApprox(waitSecs * 1000, 0.10).getFinalValue.mean
[Stage 1:======================================================> (98 + 2) / 100]cntApprxFinal: Double = 1.0E7

scala> val waitSecs = 60
waitSecs: Int = 60

//Please note that cntApprxInitila in this case, will be displayed exactly after timeout duration. In this case 80 tasks were completed within timeout and it displayed the value of variable. Even after displaying the variable value, it continued will all the remaining tasks
scala> val cntApprxInitial = inputDf.rdd.countApprox(waitSecs * 1000, 0.10).initialValue.mean
[Stage 2:============================================>           (80 + 4) / 100]cntApprxInitial: Double = 1.0E7

[Stage 2:=======================================================>(99 + 1) / 100]
```

Let's have look at spark ui and spark-shell, all 3 operations took same time:
[image: All 3 operations took same time]

`cntApprxInitial` is available before completion of all tasks.

[image: cntApprxInitial is available before completion of all tasks]

Hope, this helps!

Comment: This is a nice insight!   So .. is this supposed to be used in an asynchronous thread on the driver?

Comment: Please highlight in your answer to use **initialValue** instead of *finalValue* : that appears to be the key given the reference you provided.

Comment: I'm re-running the large-ish app now and presuming we get reasonable results will award

Comment: updated the answer. Thanks for suggestion. Please let me know if it worked for you with large-ish app

Comment: *Verified* !   `[0709-09:16:44.013] DEBUG: blocker.process: inputs are sampledIac
[0709-09:16:45.013] DEBUG: sampledIac: #Rows=5.557243954545455E8`  Took 60 seconds and had *very* good accuracy!

Comment: glad, it helped.