# pyspark countApprox() does not seem to be different from count()

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm having trouble with the `count()` method of pyspark, which is way too slow for my program. I found out about the `countApprox(timeout,confidence)` one but it doesn't speed up the process.

What i found doing a bit of research is that I should maybe use `rdd.countApprox.initialValue` but it doesn't seem to work, as in pyspark the result of `countApprox` is an int and not a `PartialResult` object (I guess it is different in scala or java)

Does anyone know how to make `countApprox` work in pyspark ?

My test code to compare :

```
a = sc.parallelize(range(1000000),10)

import time
t = time.time()
print("there are ",a.count()," rows")
print(time.time()-t)
```

gives :

```
there are  1000000  rows
3.4864296913146973
```

but

```
b = sc.parallelize(range(1000000),10)

import time
t = time.time()
print("there are ",b.countApprox(10,0.1)," rows")
print(time.time()-t)
```

gives out :

```
 there are  1000000  rows
3.338970422744751
```

Which is pretty much the same time of execution...

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51238557/rdd-countapproximate-taking-far-longer-than-requested-timeout

Answer (score 1):

countApprox works faster than count, has timeout and confidence definition. I suppose you will see the runtime difference on a big datasets.

Comment: Well the point is, I don't... I supposed so too, but it works as if there was no difference, with this little a timeout and a confidence, the difference should be notable, no ? and even with a large rdd (this one was a test one, mine is quite large) i see no difference in counting time (and the answer is always the same as count(), which is not normal ...)